# In Apache Zeppelin how can I know which libraries are conflicting?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

When I add an external library to Zeppelin's Spark interpreter, sometimes, in a very random way, the spark interpreter does not start. Some other times, it starts but then I cannot access the added library. And sometimes it just works.

My best guess is that some jars are conflicting.

This is the output error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:821)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:612)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:186)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Your Zeppelin is a running local spark? or its connected to a remote cluster?

Comment: It is a remote cluster